# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS slow, lag, hang and freeze all the time!

Tags: 12.04, unity, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my sister's laptop on 2nd partition (1st partition contains Windows XP). My sister always complaining about Ubuntu 12.04 for being slow, lags, hang and freeze all the time! The Image Viewer and GIMP always hang when opening image s above 2MB and it causes the desktop to hang as well. I have disabled all the compiz animations, but still the results are disappointing. My sister has lose her hope to use Ubuntu and she asked me to remove Ubuntu completely from her laptop. I'm really embarrassed to my sister as I always brag about Ubuntu for being good in performance, free from viruses, fast and other good stuff..  What should I do? I really want her to use Ubuntu instead of Windows.

Comment: Get a faster laptop?

Comment: @izx *Freezing* problems aren't ordinarily caused by slow hardware. **vipercobra**: I hope there turns out to be a good technical solution to this problem that enables your sister to have a smoothly running, fast Ubuntu system...but remember, one of the things Ubuntu is about is empowering users, and while Ubuntu may an excellent OS for many (or even most) computer users, it's OK if not everyone in the world chooses to use Ubuntu. If she relies on you for technical assistance and has asked you to remove Ubuntu...then you should really do that for her, saddening though it may be. ;-(

Comment: @EliahKagan: I'd say *hangs* aren't caused by slow hardware, while freezes can... where `hang = crash ~= panic` ;)

Comment: @izx A freeze means the machine, or an interface, or (rarely) a single application, stops responding to user input (without exiting). A hang is an infinite loop (though it is sometimes also used to describe deadlocks, where CPU isn't being used but a task never completes). A crash is abnormal program termination. A panic is a kernel condition where the operating system cannot continue running. At least that's how I use these terms. ;-) ...So I think freezing could be *exacerbated* (but not *caused*) by slow hardware (though mainly for I/O reasons rather than processing or memory reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the quick refreshers @EliahKagan :)  I think the OP is using slow, lag and hang as synonyms for freeze...   and yes, exacerbated is correct, not caused.